# Exception Handling - Possible ways in given scenario

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to add Exception Handling to this piece of code. The code works fine but I am looking for suggestions for other **possible/better options for Exception Handling.**

Note- This code is very basic code for finding and printing out duplicates. It's not the main focus of the concept in question.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Duplicate {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String str = " ";
    Map<Character, Integer> mapOfDuplicates = findDuplicate(str);
    for(Character each: mapOfDuplicates.keySet()) {
        if(mapOfDuplicates.get(each)>1)
      System.out.println(each + " " + mapOfDuplicates.get(each));
    }
  }

  private static Map<Character, Integer> findDuplicate(String str) throws Exception {
      if(str.isEmpty() || str==null || str.trim().isEmpty()) {
          throw new Exception("Empty or null String not allowed");
      }
    char[] inChar = str.toCharArray();
    Map<Character, Integer> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(char eachChar: inChar) {
      if(finalMap.containsKey(eachChar)) {
        int valueInHM = finalMap.get(eachChar);
        valueInHM++;
        finalMap.put(eachChar, valueInHM);
      } else {
        finalMap.put(eachChar, 1);
      }
    }
    return finalMap;
  }
}
```

There are 2 ways I can think of to handle this -

1. Add a condition in the method -

```
if(str==null) {
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null not 
}
```

2. Add NullPointerException in the end of the method -

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> findDuplicate(String str) {
        Map<Character, Integer> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            char[] inChar = str.toCharArray();

            for (char eachChar : inChar) {
                if (finalMap.containsKey(eachChar)) {
                    int valueInHM = finalMap.get(eachChar);
                    valueInHM++;
                    finalMap.put(eachChar, valueInHM);
                } else {
                    finalMap.put(eachChar, 1);
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            System.out.println("null not allowed");
        }
        return finalMap;
    }
```

Which one is more preferable and why?

Moreover, the get and put methods throw Exceptions like -

```
1. UnsupportedOperationException
2. ClassCastException 
3. NullPointerException
4. IllegalArgumentException
```

How can we handle these exceptions?

Comment: Passing an illegal argument is a bug. It should be signalled by a runtime exception, not a checked exception. Specifically, an IllegalArgumentException. Google for "Java exceptions tutorial" for basics about exceptions. Don't, ever, throw `Exception`.

Comment: Firstly, there's a risk of NPE at `if(str.isEmpty() || str==null || str.trim().isEmpty()) `. You have to fix that first. Since you couldn't proceed if input string is invalid, I suggest you should throw a runtime exception in this case an IllegalArgumentException().

Comment: Adding NullPointerException in the end of method is vague, because in this code almost exceptions caused by input string. Depend on your exception you want to hanlde the input value, but IllegalArgumentException() is good to choice

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("str may not be null/blank");
}
```